# Is it possible to open Control Panel based applications with raised privileges?

Tags: permissions, windows-xp

For example, I want to uninstall an application on a users PC whilst they are logged in, but they do not have the rights to do so in the "Add/remove Programs" application. Is it possible to use "Run as..." for Control Panel based applications so that I can open the application as an Administrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `runas` command.

```
runas /user:Administrator "control appwiz.cpl"
```

It will prompt for a password then launch Add/Remove Programs with Administrator's credentials.  There are [other control panel applets](http://samanathon.com/how-to-launch-control-panel-application-from-the-command-line/) you might need to launch this way as well.

You can also hold shift while right-clicking the applets and most of them allow you to choose "Run As".

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as Administrator using Powershell:

```
Start-Process "control.exe" -ArgumentList "appwiz.cpl" -Verb RunAs
```